# Why `address.call` function "saves" unnecessary gas for after the internal execution?

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas, multisignature, gas-estimate, callcode

I deployed a contract of a multisig wallet to ropsten and try to test its abilities:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8bf20c41ee6a9fd84e81d6f6df872d9628cd08b2

Things that worked fine:

- Withdraw ETH
- Sending transaction to other contract (transfer erc20 tokens)

Things that didn't worked as expected:

- add owner
- replace owner
- basically every wallet change transaction failed

Why and how it failed?

Example transaction: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf4074abba33252d79dcdd234071dff25c7eba205ddb777076e623d6d108b7392

First I use the wallet `submitTransaction` function and submitted a transaction to the same wallet contract with data that call the internal transaction change, `addOwner`.
Then I used another owner key to confirm it.
When the transaction got the required confirmations the contract called the method `executeTransaction` which execute this call:

`txn.destination.call.value(txn.value)(txn.data)`

In this example

`txn.data` is `0x7065cb480000000000000000000000009ac4f6e64d56043991f486e375994f67ecbfdde0` calling `addOwner("0x9ac4f6e64d56043991f486e375994f67ecbfdde0")`

`txn.value` is `0`

As you can see, the internal transaction is failing due to `out of gas`.

Did a little research and found out that after the `call` function, the contract "saves" some gas for after the internal transaction invoke, and the internal transaction invoked with only 700 gas that consumed immediately by the `CALL` opcode.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xf4074abba33252d79dcdd234071dff25c7eba205ddb777076e623d6d108b7392
line 728:
[image: Gas consumption]

Funny thing is, that at the end of the external transaction, the execution left with 27511 gas.

Some other wired stuff:

- If I give the transaction a lot of gas (x10) [it works fine](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x88a403564cea66d15f6d582651d8aafd39bb9cac087e099cd4247574a374af4c).
- If I use different contract to interact with (for example `erc20.transfer`) [it works fine](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x78059b2a9a6514b50522f2d67b3eb9c2503ad256ee0480e9696f9f9fe51d41da).
- If I use the `executeTransaction` by itself (after the transaction is confirmed), [it works fine](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xccee65fd86952f853a1158406fee4aab8133f96b20c3adc216149a12284a51a1).

So, What is going on? Why the gas estimation not working?

PS I tried it both with MEW and web3 js code for gas estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is some unexpected behavior in the solidity compiler:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2999

Works on `pragma experimental "v0.5.0";` with compiler 0.4.18.